# SharePoint 2010 Reporting Services Integrated Mode error on client

Tags: reporting-services, integrated-mode

I am examine the different possibilities of SharePoint & Reporting Services Native Mode vs. Integrated Mode. So i set up an environment with both possibilities.

I have a SharePoint farm with following components:
SQL Server 2008 + Reporting Services (Native Mode)
SharePoint 2010 Server + Reporting Services (SharePoint Integrated Mode)

On the SharePoint server i am able to view the reports that are on my reporting server in native mode as the ones that are in Integrated Mode.

But when I browse from a client pc to my sharepoint site, I only can access the reports from Native Mode. Those of SharePoint Integrated Mode return the following error

```
   Cannot create a connection to data source 'MY-SQLSERVER-NAME'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
```

Do i run into the double hop problem (I use NTLM)? Or is there another issue?

Comment: It looks like a normal authentication issue, unless you are using claims? Anyway try adding this as a datasource and store the credentials inside it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159736.aspx

Comment: When i use no "Windows authentication (integrated) or SharePoint user" for the data source it did not work <- Initial set up. But if i change the data source settings to use stored credentials, it works now on the client pc. But what if i do not want to use stored credentials???

Comment: I have added as an answer, since it does work in this situation. It may not be seamless but it works all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the connection as a data source following this technet article [Storing Credentials For a Data Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159736.aspx)

While this may not be a seamless solution it will work, and I don't know of another solution to get around this issue at present.

I have found that it is usually few people running reporting, so it isn't hard to roll out. Creating trusted data sources is the best way to go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

based on the error that you got its a generic error. MS have outlined 5 cases for it:

> Cannot create a connection to data source 'datasourcename'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
>
> ---
>
> This is a generic error that occurs when the report server cannot open
>   a connection to an external data source that provides data to a
>   report. This error appears with a second error message that indicates
>   the underlying cause. The following additional errors can appear with
>   rsErrorOpeningConnection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx

you can try:

changing Report Server Service to run as "Local Service". But by doing this the
creating report models is now completed in Report Manager.

hope it helps :)

Comment: Strange thing is that it works perfect with the same user on my SharePoint server. It is when i want to access it with that user on a computer that is not my SharePoint server.